# Connect a local version of project with Github

Tags: git, github

Scenario:

I manually downloaded a zip of a file (a web app) that I am using locally. I want to start pushing some fixes. I don't want to have to download the entire project again (low bandwidth, expensive internet)

So, is there anyway to connect the local project to Git repository and have it use my local version as the base (adding the relevant changes, if any, of course).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to turn a local folder into a git repository OR you want to point a clone of a repo to a local `remote` ?

Comment: I want to get the same results as `git clone <remote>` without having to download all the files I already have locally (from a previous zip download)

Comment: Then see the first part of my answer `git clone --reference <repository>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use git clone and get it to point to a local copy of the repository (assuming your downloaded zip file is a git repo)

From the [git manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

`git clone --reference <repository>`

> If the reference repository is on the local machine, automatically
>   setup .git/objects/info/alternates to obtain objects from the
>   reference repository. Using an already existing repository as an
>   alternate will require fewer objects to be copied from the repository
>   being cloned, reducing network and local storage costs

**git clone --depth 1**

If you only wanted a shallow clone of a remote repo (let's say you just want to patch HEAD and submit), this would save on bandwidth by only cloning the recent history.

Comment: so would the full command be: `get clone --references <local repo> <remote repo>` that would mean I need to set up the local instance as a repo first?

Comment: Yes the local instance would need to be a repo. Then you would just type `git clone --reference <local repo path>`

Comment: You don't pass two options. It will clone from one `remote`. Remember that as git is distributed each clone of a repo is essentially the same. If you wanted to add another `remote` (so you can push locally and over the internet) you can use `git remote add <name> <remote repo>`

Answer (score 1):

Locate the folder of the project, then add this project from the client, in e.g. from windows client. When you add that repository, the client should check the files and if they are exact copies, it should not download again.

Comment: Then you should use shell and git commands, as @lebreeze suggested: git clone --reference <repository>